# How to determine the display count of a Swift String?

Tags: swift, string, emoji-tones

I've reviewed questions such as [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string) and [Why are emoji characters like 👩‍👩‍👧‍👦 treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings) but neither cover this specific question.

This all started when trying to apply skin tone modifiers to Emoji characters (see [Add skin tone modifier to an emoji programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674968/add-skin-tone-modifier-to-an-emoji-programmatically)). This led to wondering what happens when you apply a skin tone modifier to a regular character such as `"A"`.

Examples:

```
let tonedThumbsUp = "" + "" // 
let tonedA = "A" + "" // A
```

I'm trying to detect that second case. The `count` of both of those strings is 1. And the `unicodeScalars.count` is 2 for both.

How do I determine if the resulting string appears as a single character when displayed? In other words, how can I determine if the skin tone modifier was applied to make a single character or not?

I've tried a few ways to dump information about the string but none give the desired result.

```
func dumpString(_ str: String) {
    print("Raw:", str, str.count)
    print("Scalars:", str.unicodeScalars, str.unicodeScalars.count)
    print("UTF16:", str.utf16, str.utf16.count)
    print("UTF8:", str.utf8, str.utf16.count)
    print("Range:", str.startIndex, str.endIndex)
    print("First/Last:", str.first == str.last, str.first, str.last)
}

dumpString("A")
dumpString("\u{1f469}\u{1f3fe}")
```

Results:

```
Raw: A 1
Scalars: A 2
UTF16: A 3
UTF8: A 3
First/Last: true Optional("A") Optional("A")
Raw:  1
Scalars:  2
UTF16:  4
UTF8:  4
First/Last: true Optional("") Optional("")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you print  on a system that doesn't support the Fitzpatrick modifiers? You get  followed by whatever the system uses for an unknown character placeholder.

So I think to answer this, you must consult your system's typesetter. For Apple platforms, you can use Core Text to create a `CTLine` and then count the line's glyph runs. Example:

```
import Foundation
import CoreText

func test(_ string: String) {
    let richText = NSAttributedString(string: string)
    let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(richText as CFAttributedString)
    let runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line) as! [CTRun]
    print(string, runs.count)
}

test("" + "")
test("A" + "")
test("B\u{0300}\u{0301}\u{0302}" + "")
```

Output from a macOS playground in Xcode 10.2.1 on macOS 10.14.6 Beta (18G48f):

```
 1
A 2
B̀́̂ 2
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I looked at this answer on my Mac, the accents in the output were piled in a stack above the `B`. But now looking at it on my iPad (running iPadOS 13.0 beta 2), they are spread out horizontally between the `B` and the Fitzpacktrick modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be possible to reason about this by looking to see whether the modifier is present and if so whether it has increased the character count.

So for example:

```
let tonedThumbsUp = "" + ""
let tonedA = "A" + ""
tonedThumbsUp.count // 1
tonedThumbsUp.unicodeScalars.count // 2
tonedA.count //2
tonedThumbsUp.unicodeScalars.count //2
let c = "\u{1F3FB}"
tonedThumbsUp.contains(c) // true
tonedA.contains(c) // true
```

Okay, so they both contain a modifier character, and they both contain two unicode scalars, but one is count 1 and the other is count 2. Surely that's a useful distinction.

Comment: `tonedA.count` returns `1` for me in an Xcode 11 beta 2 playground. That's also what I show in my question (though as `"A"` instead of `"A" + ""` but both give a count of 1) and that's really the whole basis of my question.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that too. In a way that’s the weirdest part. The switch to underlying utf8 may have caused that. I wonder if it’s a bug.